# angular service dies before controller is invoked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, dependency-injection, browserify

I'm working on an angular app that consumes a public API. I can't seem to pass the service object into the controller. The error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchRole' of undefined
```

on this line:

```
var model = govtracksvc.searchRole();
```

When I step through in the debugger, it hits the service file first. govtrack & govtracksvc are both created, and govtrack is injected. Then the service object dies at the end of the file, because when it invokes the controller file, the service variables are undefined. I am missing the link that keeps the service object alive when the app steps into the controller file. Any help would be tremendous.

## rep.module.js

```
(function () {
    var angular = require('angular');  //browserify bundling with NPM
    angular.module('RepresentativeApp', []);
    require('./rep.service.js');
    require('./Rep.js');

})();
```

## rep.service.js

```
var govtracksvc = (function () {
    angular
        .module('RepresentativeApp')
        .factory('govtracksvc', govtracksvc);

    var govtrack = require('govtrack-node');

    govtracksvc.$inject = ['govtrack'];

    function govtracksvc(govtrack) {
        var service = { searchRole: searchRole };
        return service;
        function searchRole(obj) { //do stuff }
    }
})();
```

## Rep.js

```
var Rep = (function () {
    angular
        .module('RepresentativeApp')
        .controller('Rep', [Rep]);

    Rep.$inject = ['govtracksvc'];

    function Rep(govtracksvc) {
        var model = govtracksvc.searchRole();
        return model;
    }
})();
```

## Update

I haven't gotten to the bottom of this yet, but I believe this has to do with how browserify bundles the module. I think the IIFEs are part of the issue.

Comment: WHy are you using $inject?

Comment: 'govtrack' service isn't defined in your example. You don't need to do anything to keep the dependency 'alive'. If it was injected, it was injected, if it was not, it was not.

Comment: @YuriZarubin $inject adds the dependency - for the controller the dependency is the factory. for the factory the dependency is the govtrack object.

Comment: @estus govtracksvc is defined in rep.service.js. The problem is that the variables are undefined when the controller script runs. It injects an undefined 'govtracksvc'

Comment: Yeah, but why are you using $inject for that? The idiomatic angular way to define dependencies is simply `.controller(function(yourDependency) { yourDependency.foo() })`. Why use array notation along with $inject? its just strange.

Comment: @YuriZarubin it is usually referred as 'John Papa style', though JP wasn't the first guy who used it.

Comment: @Kraken Then you're not providing all the relevant code. The above code would throw an error because 'govtrack' (not 'govtracksvc') service is not defined.

Comment: @YuriZarubin Check this out: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @estus I beg to differ. govtracksvc is most definitely defined.

Comment: You're injecting 'govtrack' service here `govtracksvc(govtrack) {`. And 'govtrack' service isn't defined.

Comment: @estus - as I said the service is created, the dependency is injected into the service. The problem is that the service does not stay alive long enough. I am debugging the browserify tasks currently. I believe that is the source of the problem, but I can't figure out exactly which syntax is needed to build it right.

Comment: @estus govtracksvc is actually defined here: angular.module('RepresentativeApp').factory('govtracksvc', govtracksvc);

Comment: Sorry, 'does not stay alive long enough' doesn't make sense in the context of Angular services. I didn't make a typo when I typed 'govtrack', I copy-pasted it from your code. You're injecting it into 'govtracksvc'.

Comment: @estus - The service is defined in the .factory invocation. As stated in my last comment.

Comment: What part of "I can see it defined, then injected, then the variable is undefined" does not make sense?

Comment: It depends on how you 'see' it. It can't be that way because Angular services are singletons, and once 'govtracksvc' is an object, it won't become 'undefined'.

Comment: You don't have `.factory('govtrack', ...` anywhere in your code. Without it you can't inject 'govtrack' into 'govtracksvc' . That's the point. You didn't provide all the relevant code. It is impossible to figure out what can be wrong from that code pieces that you've posted. They look fine.

Comment: @estus Oh! I see what you are asking about. govtrack is actually entirely self contained. It is a public API. You can declare it anywhere once the node module is required. https://www.npmjs.com/package/govtrack-node

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can't just inject 'govtrack' local variable to 'govtracksvc' service. Angular DI doesn't work like that. You have to do something like `angular.module('...').value('govtrack', require('govtrack-node'))` to be able to inject it into 'govtracksvc' service. Without it Angular should throw [an injection error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr). The fact that you haven't got that error means that something fishy happens there, something that the posted code cannot explain.

Comment: @estus - govtrack instantiates without any problem whatsoever. You can see it in the browser and it has all the correct functions and properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the API object in as .value(). Much easier solution!